# Create associative array with arrays as values

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

In cs4 I am attempting to create an associative array where the values are arrays. These arrays have just two elements and I want to call one of these two elements like this:

```
var array1:Array = [5, "Example String"]
var array2:Array = [7, "Example String 2"]
var associativeArray:Object = {a1:array1, a2:array2}

trace(associativeArray[a1[0]]) // Print out the value of the first element of the first array. Should print out 5
```

However this does not print out the first element. Curiously if you omit the "[0]" the program does print the entire array like this: "5, Example String".

How would I go about printing just one element from the array which is inside the associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of arguments is wrong in your square bracket access operator **[ ]**. You need to use the correct notation:

```
// The whole collection.
trace(associativeArray);

// The collection element, square bracket notation.
// The key MUST be a String.
trace(associativeArray["a1"]);

// The collection element, dot notation.
trace(associativeArray.a1);

// Access the element of collection element.
trace(associativeArray["a1"][0]);
trace(associativeArray.a1[0]);

// WRONG. Access non-existent element of the collection.
trace(associativeArray[a1[0]]);
trace(associativeArray["a1"[0]]);
```